# How can I add HTML elements to stash mixed with text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I'm adding a string with HTML `<br>` within it to the stash. This stash value is then used to populate a text area.

The problem is the browser converts the `>` and `<`  to `lt;` and `gt;` and it displays wrong in the browser. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

```
$string = "line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3";
$self->stash(info => $string);
$self->render('infopage');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display text, you use this:

```
<%= $var %>
```

Or this

```
%= $var
```

This syntax will convert > to gt; and < to lt;

You must to use this syntax if you want to to except conversation

```
<%== $var %>
```

Or this

```
%== $var
```

So, simply add symbol =, but it is not security.

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple solution to my problem. I missed this in the documentation.  "<%= Perl expression, replaced with result %>
<%== Perl expression, replaced with XML escaped result %>"